# How to get proper TeX output from splicing the following file?

Tags: latex, templates

*In order to let other users with Mathematica 12.x test this problem for me, I now use `FileTemplate` instead of `Splice`.*

I want to splice (with `FileTemplate`) the following file that has been simplified for the sake of illustration purpose only.

```
% input.mtex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}
<* 
   students = {{"Andy", 2}, {"Bob", 3}, {"Cindy", 5}, {"David", 1}, {"Eve", 9}};
*>
\end{comment}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
<*
 StringTemplate["\\item `name` can run at \\SI{`speed`}{\\meter\\per\\second}."][<|"name" -> #[[1]], "speed" -> #[[2]]|>] & /@ students
*>
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The preamble of LaTeX document has been trimmed in the code that follow. It is just for simplicity.

## Unexpected Output

```
\begin{enumerate}
{
 \item  can run at \SI{}{\meter\per\second}.[<|name -> Andy, speed -> 2|>], 
 \item  can run at \SI{}{\meter\per\second}.[<|name -> Bob, speed -> 3|>], 
 \item  can run at \SI{}{\meter\per\second}.[<|name -> Cindy, speed -> 5|>], 
 \item  can run at \SI{}{\meter\per\second}.[<|name -> David, speed -> 1|>], 
 \item  can run at \SI{}{\meter\per\second}.[<|name -> Eve, speed -> 9|>]
}
\end{enumerate}
```

## Expected Output

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Andy can run at \SI{2}{\meter\per\second}.
    \item Bob can run at \SI{3}{\meter\per\second}.
    \item Cindy can run at \SI{5}{\meter\per\second}.
    \item David can run at \SI{1}{\meter\per\second}.
    \item Eve can run at \SI{9}{\meter\per\second}.
\end{enumerate}
```

## Question

What is the proper way to splice it to get the expected output?

---

**Update by Szabolcs:**

The unexpected output seems to be due to the nesting of templates and can be reproduced with these smaller examples:

```
In[1]:= StringTemplate["x<* StringTemplate[\"a``b\"][123] *>y"][]
Out[1]= "xab[123]y"

In[2]:= TemplateApply[TemplateExpression[StringTemplate["a``b"][123]]]
Out[2]= "ab"[123]
```

`Out[1]` should be `xa123by` and `Out[2]` should be `a123b`.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use `FileTemplate`? `Splice` has been changed in 12.1. People who have 12.1 cannot even test this for you.

Comment: You failed to quote backslashes in strings. Can you fix that first please?

Comment: One problem with using a template within a template is that delimiters will conflict. You have those backtick-delimited slots "name" and "speed". Are these slots of the outer file template or the inner string template? I would suggest using different delimiters for the two levels.

Comment: `"\item"` is invalid Mathematiac code. You must use `"\\item"`.

Comment: You use ``"`name`"`` in your file template. You meant it as a slot in the StringTemplate that is contained within the file template. But it is actually picked up by the `FileTemplate` first. Use a different separator than a backtick in `FileTemplate`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Is there a better way to obtain the expected output than what I did above? Actually I don't like quoting the TeX contents as a string, especially with escape sequence double backslashes. Readability is the first priority.

Comment: "I don't like quoting the TeX contents as a string" It's not about like or dislike. Your code is plainly wrong and triggers error messages. You were lucky that you didn't hit on an existing escape sequence, e.g. `"\text"` has a tab at the start.

Comment: There's something more to this than the delimiters, and I do not fully understand what is going on. BTW you misunderstood what I meant. I'll edit your post a bit to clarify, please revert if you disagree with the edit.

Comment: Actually, I was completely wrong about the delimiters causing a problem. In this case they do not seem to be. (The `\\` thing was still important, but again not the cause of the problem you see.)

Comment: A more minimal example of the problem is the following: ```StringTemplate["<* StringTemplate[\"``\"][123] *>"][]```. The output is `"[123]"`. I would expect `"123"` (without the `[` and `]`). It must be somehow related to the nesting of templates ...

Comment: I am sorry, I give up ... I would say that this is either due to a bug (shouldn't happen) or nested templates are not supported (which should have been documented, and preferably protected against). Of course, it is a very reasonable question to ask how to splice the output into such a template of a TeX file.